# Nested macro calls

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, c99

Trying to have nested macro calls as below:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define INT
#define LONG

#define AS(t) AS_##t
#define AS_INT as_int
#define AS_LONG as_long

#define LET(v, t) v. AS(t)

typedef union
{
    int32_t as_int;
    int64_t as_long;
} mytype_t;

int main()
{
    mytype_t s;

    s.AS(INT) = 10;    /* This is OK */

    LET(s, INT) = 10;  /* This makes error */

    return 0;
}
```

It makes error:

```
main.c:xx:yy: error: ‘mytype_t {aka union <anonymous>}’ has no member named ‘AS_’
 #define LET(v, t) v. AS(t)
                    ^
main.c:zz:ww: note: in expansion of macro ‘LET’
     LET(s, INT) = 10;
     ^~~
```

Is there any workaround to have `LET(s, INT) = 10;` ?

Comment: Why are you using macros? Seems to make the code a lot more unreadable and more difficult to debug.

Comment: Try `#undef INT` before the line that contains `LET(s, INT) = 10;  /* This makes error */`

Comment: I know these kinds of tricks can have a certain appeal to them, sort of like defining a domain-specific language, but please consider just using `s.as_int` directly instead of going through these macros. Future readers, possibly including your future self, will thank you for it… =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's these two *empty* macros

```
#define INT
#define LONG
```

`INT` when passed into `AS(t)` via `LET` undergoes intermediate expansion, and is expanded to an empty token sequence before `AS()` itself is expanded. As such you concatenate `AS_` with an empty token sequence. Just drop these two macros, having `AS_INT` and `AS_LONG` defined is enough for your example.

Answer (score 1):

It has been answered that the error was due to empty macros.

Another solution can be:

```
#define INT INT
#define LONG LONG
```

Hope this helps.